# Cache is not clearing, deleted template is still loading

Tags: theming, caching

I created a new node template named node--artist-page.tpl.php and it worked fine. but then, (i'm brand new at this) when saw i made some errors with it i tried deleting it but Drupal keeps loading it!

i can tell because i echoe'd out an alert saying the 'my new node tpl is running'

in addition to clearing the cache (5 or more times) I even put it in the trash but it still loads!, anyone have any experience like this? or know how to fix?

am really stuck right now.

Comment: What cache have you delteted? Make sure to delete ALL cache. If you use drush, try this: 'drush cc', then choose 1 (all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you clear your browser cache as well as Drupals.  Also it's worth checking you're making the changes in the right template files.  You could do this by switching templates in > admin > appeRances .

I hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

that file was in the CSS folder! i knew i'd mistakenly saved one there but then immediately resaved to the template folder. then, deleted the one in the template folder and forgot about the one in the CSS folder.

when i finally removed it (from the CSS folder) then the default template did indeed load, weird